# Ajax retornando undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Coloquei um else na minha função em php e ele está caindo no else, mas eu tenho parametros para pegar da url.

Tenho o seguinte código em php:

```
$utm_source = $_REQUEST['utm_source'];
$utm_campaign = $_REQUEST['utm_campaign'];
$utm_medium = $_REQUEST['utm_medium'];
if($utm_source != '' || $utm_campaign != '' || $utm_medium != '')
{
    $x['x'] = $utm_source;
    $x['y'] = $utm_campaign;
    $x['k'] = $utm_medium;
    echo json_encode($x);
}
```

Quando eu acesso direto o arquivo pelo navegador com os parametros ?utm_source=xesquedele&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=parceiros ele me retorna:

```
{"x":"xesquedele","y":"parceiros","k":"site"}
```

Mas quando eu tento retornar isso pra um ajax ele não me retorna nada ou undefined.

```
$j(document).ready(function()
{
    $j.ajax({
        url: '/inchoo_quoteitemrule/ajax/sessiondesconto',
        method: "POST",
        success: function(retorno)
        {
            console.log(retorno);
            alert('utm_medium: '+retorno['k']+' utm_source: '+retorno['x']+' utm_campaign: '+retorno['y']);
        }
    });
});
```

Retorno do ajax: utm_medium: undefined utm_source: undefined utm_campaign: undefined

Comment: Já tentou colocar `dataType:"json",` no Ajax?

Comment: Eu coloquei, consegui resolver a questão, mas tive que usar outros métodos.

Answer (score 1):

A superglobal `$_REQUEST` retorna informações das superglobais `$_GET`, `$_POST` e `$_COOKIE`. No seu primeiro exemplo você está mandando esses dados via `GET`, ou seja, pela url. E tudo funcionou bem, já que os dados estavam sendo enviados. Já no seu segundo exemplo você não está populando nenhuma das 3 superglobais. Seu código ajax vai funcionar se você mandar dessa forma

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j.ajax({
        url: '/inchoo_quoteitemrule/ajax/sessiondesconto',
        method: "POST",
        data:{utm_source: 'xesquedele',utm_medium:'site',utm_campaign:'parceiros'},
        success: function(retorno) {
            console.log(retorno);
        }
    });
});
```

Veja que estou mandando os dados no pedido AJAX via post. e os dados retornam perfeitamente.

Lembrando que, seu alert não está funcionando pois você está retornando uma string do seu servidor. Você precisa transformar essa string em um objeto Javascript. Para isso você pode usar a função `jQuery.parseJSON()`. Ficaria algo como:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j.ajax({
        url: '/inchoo_quoteitemrule/ajax/sessiondesconto',
        method: "POST",
        data:{utm_source: 'xesquedele',utm_medium:'site',utm_campaign:'parceiros'},
        success: function(retorno) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(retorno);
            console.log(retorno);
            alert('utm_medium: '+obj.k+' utm_source: '+obj.x+' utm_campaign: '+obj.y);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Eu não posso passar esses valores na "mão", teria que pegar eles dinamicamente de acordo com a url e não posso usar um $_REQUEST e retornar isso para o php pq vai cachear.. O jeito vai ser eu pegar pelo jquery o link e quebrar ele pegando os valores que eu gostaria, obrigado.

Comment: É uma opção fazer isso.

Comment: Eu procurei uma função para tal. var url = location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf('?') + 1) mas ai terei que quebrar a string e retornar, mas pelo menos não irá cachear..